# How to use calendar-cursor-to-visible-date without switching to *Calendar*

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have not been able to figure out why `with-current-buffer` or `set-buffer` does not work with the function `calendar-cursor-to-visible-date`.  I would like the function to work without actually switching to the calendar window -- i.e., it should work even when the buffer is buried.  I've tried `sit-for 0`, but that had no affect.

I've included a `broken-example` using `with-current-buffer` and a `working-example` using `select-window`.

---

**EDIT**:  I found a similar issue on an Emacs mailing list from March 2005:  http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-pretest-bug/2005-03/msg00170.html   I'll do some more testing, but the following line of code fixes the `broken-example` -- it goes immediately after `(calendar-cursor-to-visible-date date)`.

```
(set-window-point (get-buffer-window "*Calendar*" (selected-frame)) (point)))
```

---

```
(defun broken-example (&optional month year)
(interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (if (get-buffer "*Calendar*")
    (kill-buffer "*Calendar*"))
  (calendar)
  (other-window 1)
  (when (get-buffer "*Calendar*")
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "*Calendar*")
      (calendar-generate-window month year)
      (let ((old-date (calendar-cursor-to-date))
           (today (calendar-current-date)))
        (cond
          ((and
              (calendar-date-is-visible-p old-date)
              (not (equal old-date today)))
            (calendar-cursor-to-visible-date old-date))
          ((calendar-date-is-visible-p today)
            (calendar-cursor-to-visible-date today))
          (t
            (calendar-cursor-to-visible-date (list month 1 year))))))))

(defun working-example (&optional month year)
(interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (if (get-buffer "*Calendar*")
    (kill-buffer "*Calendar*"))
  (calendar)
  (other-window 1)
  (when (get-buffer "*Calendar*")
    (select-window (get-buffer-window "*Calendar*" (selected-frame)))
      (calendar-generate-window month year)
      (let ((old-date (calendar-cursor-to-date))
           (today (calendar-current-date)))
        (cond
          ((and
              (calendar-date-is-visible-p old-date)
              (not (equal old-date today)))
            (calendar-cursor-to-visible-date old-date))
          ((calendar-date-is-visible-p today)
            (calendar-cursor-to-visible-date today))
          (t
            (calendar-cursor-to-visible-date (list month 1 year)))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my recommendation:

```
(with-selected-window (or (get-buffer-window (current-buffer) 0)
                          (selected-window))
  (calendar-cursor-to-visible-date date))
```

Of course, calling `set-window-point` after the fact is a perfectly acceptable alternative as well.

Answer (score 0):

December 25, 2013:  First working draft of the revised function `calendar-cursor-to-visible-date`, which uses `set-window-point`:

```
(defun lawlist-calendar-cursor-to-visible-date (date)
  "Move the cursor to DATE that is on the screen."
  (let* (
      (month (calendar-extract-month date))
      (day (calendar-extract-day date))
      (year (calendar-extract-year date))
      (buffer (buffer-name)))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-line (+ calendar-first-date-row -1
                     (/ (+ day -1
                           (mod
                            (- (calendar-day-of-week (list month 1 year))
                               calendar-week-start-day)
                            7))
                        7)))
    (move-to-column (+ calendar-left-margin (1- calendar-day-digit-width)
                       (* calendar-month-width
                          (1+ (calendar-interval
                               displayed-month displayed-year month year)))
                       (* calendar-column-width
                          (mod
                           (- (calendar-day-of-week date)
                              calendar-week-start-day)
                           7))))
    (if (get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame))
      (set-window-point (get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame)) (point)))))
```